# D3.js not updating data

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js, bar-chart

I am updating a D3 stacked bar graph in combination with AngularJS. In this, all data is initially visible, and updates filter out undesired data.  In the past it has worked without issue using this model:

```
data = [{
    name: John Doe, 
    splits: [{distance: 1, time: 1234},]
},...]
```

Now I am attempting to to add one more bar to each stack using this model:

```
data = [{
    name: John Doe
    time: 12345, 
    splits: [{distance: 1, time: 1234},]
},...]
```

My issue is updating the data. My calculated values are recalculated correctly, such as the domain for scaling. A line for `time` update still only recognizes the data values from before the update (code snippet heavily truncated for brevity):

```
// Set ranges of values in axes
x.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.name}));
y.domain([ min , max]);

// Y Axis is updated to the correct time range
chart.append('g').attr('class', 'y axis').call(yAxis).selectAll('text').style('font-family','Open Sans').style('font-size', '.9rem'); 

// data join / Select Athlete
var athlete = chart.selectAll(".athlete").data(data),
athdata = athlete.enter(),

console.log(data) // data is correct here

// add container for each athlete
athplace = athdata.append("g")
  .attr("class", "athlete")
  .attr("transform", function(d) {  return "translate(" + x(d.name) + ",0)"; })
  .text(function(d) { return d.name}),

// ENTER time
athplace.append('rect')
.attr('class', "time")
.attr("width", x.rangeBand())
.attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.time.time); })
.attr("height", 0).transition().duration(300)
.attr("height", function(d) {  return height-y(d.time); });

... enter splits & labels

// exit splits & athlete
splitlabels.exit().transition().duration(300).attr('opacity', 0).remove();
splits.exit().transition().duration(300).attr('height', 0).attr('opacity', 0).remove();
athlete.exit().transition().duration(300).attr('width',0).attr('opacity', 0).remove();

console.log(athlete) // data is still correct

// UPDATE time, this chain has the problem with data not being updated. "d" is equal to previous values
athlete.selectAll('rect.time')
.attr("width", x.rangeBand())
.attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.time.time); })
.attr("height", function(d) {  return height-y(d.time); });
```

Due to these errors, the updated columns represent the wrong data and produce the wrong visualization.  I have been staring/testing at this all day trying to isolate the issue to what I have now. Could someone more experienced with D3 give me some insight?

Note: for those interested, this is all in an Angular directive where I `$watch` for changes to the data values, although I am 100% sure that that is not the issue.

### Edit

Here is a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8a4872ms/10/) that illustrates the same error as in my script. All of the code was extracted directly from the script exhibiting the issue. The interval update at the bottom imitates the swapping of data that would normally happen.

Comment: do you have a fiddle?

Comment: Making a fiddle now.

Comment: I just added a JSFiddle at the bottom of the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I played with your example for a little bit and made a few changes that may be of use.

First, I re-factored your global `var`'s up top to inside your `update` function. By doing this, we are not "double-appending" where our `x` and `y` axis left off. This was seemingly drawing our chart on top of our old chart.

However, fixing this then gave me the new chart overlaying on top of our old. To fix this, I call `d3.selectAll("svg > *").remove();` within `update` to remove all attached SVG elements and groupings, giving us a "clean slate" to render our new chart on. This solves the overlaying issue.

You mention this is shortened for brevity, so I hope this example can help with your actual application

---

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8a4872ms/12/)

Comment: The fiddle was actually much closer to my actual implementation than the code snippet included. Your example does exactly what I had hoped for the graph to accomplish. Thank you for taking the time to solve this problem!

Comment: Hi, I'm also facing the same issue.

I am getting new data from server which has new axis and other attributes, data is loaded fine and on logging, showing the data as expected.

However, on update block of chart, it's plotting with old data. Not working on latest data.

I also have resolved the same by first removing the "g" nodes form chart & then re-plotting.

What it' like, we first need to remove nodes, it should update elements without that?

Thanks,

Comment: Have you posted a question yet? I'd encourage to do so with all the details you have along with a working example if you can which reproduces the issue. From your reply above I don't have enough information to make a suggestion, but I'll gladly look if you write up a question and share the link here so I can see it